# Browser Issue/Difference for pdfs defined within <object>

Tags: html, pdf, cross-browser

The following html code has been used to experiment with how different browsers handle a pdf created through the  html control.  Below is a very basic html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<body>
        <object data="http://www.dol.gov/ebsa/pdf/401kfefm.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="500" height="300">
            <p>Missing PDF plugin for this browser.
            <a href="http://www.dol.gov/ebsa/pdf/401kfefm.pdf">Click here to download the PDF file.</a></p>
        </object>
</body>
</html>
```

The pdf file will load properly in all of the browsers I have tested; Firefox 5, IE 8, Chrome 12.x, Safari 5.  However the size of the control seems to vary between IE and the other browsers.  Between the other three browsers the size is consistent but I ideally would like the control to be the same size on all browsers.

The picture below shows the size difference between Chrome and IE.
[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what is `control` in your statement, the Object Element or the controls box that the browser provides for scrolling, zooming etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is probably going on wrong with the pixels size. Try set the '500px' instead of '500' or percentage ('20%')
Hope this helps

Comment: The inclusion of px in object width/height made no difference but using percents gave me the same behavior on all 4 browsers so thanks.  Must be a difference between what a pixel is in IE vs. other browsers or just a bug for IE8.